# laravel 5.6 not redirecting properly

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am setting laravel 5.6 in a subfolder but it is giving error the page is not redirecting properly. I have tried everything with the htaceess. I have setup the htacess at the root folder as well as the public folder but it is not working
My root htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

and here is my htacess for public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /charity-frontmode/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using Apache VirtualHost ? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Yes but I am setting it on my dev server so no virtual host can be setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry I Tried it as well but to no avail

Comment: what do you get on site?

Comment: it seems to be working now I am missing some thing in my code. Make a upvote please. Thanks